# How to retrieve Sharepoint 2010 list item permissions using Javascript Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

My function for checking List Item permissions in Sharepoint doesn't seem to work. It is placed in aspx file on a Sharepoint 2010 site. I'm getting an error message below when trying to run it. Does anyone know how it should be done ? I found plenty of examples for the same function in C# but can't find anything in Javascript. Thanks !

```
function checkPermissions(){
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oBooksList=ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('test Repository');
var listItem=oBooksList.getItemById(2);


//ctx.load(listItem.get_roleAssignments());
ctx.load(listItem, 'RoleAssignments');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSucceededCallback),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailedCallback));

}
function onSucceededCallback(sender, args){
    alert('it worked');
}
```

Error message:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'apply': object is null or undefined
```

Comment: Only thing I can see... (unless it is an omission on purpose) is that there is no `onFailedCallback` function in your code.. That would cause something similar as it calls `Function.prototype.apply` or `onFailedCallback.apply` upon completion.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it works after adding onFailedCallback function. However I have difficulty with retrieving callback data, so I can't check if returned data is correct. Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: If I remember correctly the fail callback only has 1 argument and that is the error.I think error.get_message() has the error message in it

Comment: actually it has 2.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx

`function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}`

Comment: Callback run succesfully as onSucceededCallback has been called. I had a look at the Object that was returned in args and it didn't have permission information. So it looks like there is something wrong with my initiall query....

Comment: I recommend reading thought the api at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538253(v=office.14).aspx it has 'enough' useful info to get you on your way... in regards to getting the role assignments you are after `ctx.load(listItem.get_roleAssignments()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee551126(v=office.14).aspx this will return a collection that you will need to iterate over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help....

**UNTESTED**

```
function checkPermissions(){
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oBooksList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('test Repository');
    var listItem = oBooksList.getItemById(2);
    var roles = listItem.get_roleAssignments();

    ctx.load(roles);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        // success
        function (sender, args){
            var roleInfo = '';
            var roleEnumerator = roles.getEnumerator();
            // enumerate the roles
            while (roleEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var role = roleEnumerator.get_current();
                var principal = role.get_member();
                // get the principal
                ctx.load(principal);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                    // success
                    function (sender, args){
                        // alert the title
                        alert(principal.get_title());
                    }, 
                    // failure
                    function (sender, args){
                        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
                    });
            }
        }, 
        // failure
        function (sender, args){
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
        });

}
```

Comment: In the `while`-loop there is a small scoping issue, changing `var principal` into `let principal` should solve this. But in any case a good solution.